# How to sort XML in LINQ C# by an attribute value? Also MVC

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

(Using the latest MVC 2 RC 2) I'm trying to sort some XML in LINQ (C#) by an element's attribute's value...

```
var sites = from s in xDoc.Element("sites").Elements("site")
orderby s.Attribute("name")
select s;
```

But when I pass this to my View I get the exception:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
Source Error: 
Line 37:                </th>
Line 38:            </tr>
Line 39:            <% foreach (var item in Model)
Line 40:               { %>
Line 41:            <tr>
```

Can someone tell me how to sort XML using LINQ and have it render properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I think you just want:

```
var sites = from s in xDoc.Element("sites").Elements("site")
            orderby (string) s.Attribute("name")
            select s;
```

Which could also be written as:

```
var sites = xDoc.Element("sites")
                .Elements("site")
                .OrderBy(s => (string) s.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're correct- I had copied the wrong piece of code into my post! Argh. I've corrected it now.

Comment: The 'site' variable is the value I'm passing into my view, eg: return View(site);

Comment: You may want to replace orderby (string) s.Attribute("name") by         orderby s.Attribute("name").Value

Comment: @VitaliClimenco: That depends on what you want to happen if the element doesn't have a `name` attribute. Using `.Value` it will throw an exception; using the cast it will just be ordered at the start (as nulls are).