# How to sort XML document in linq by an attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting, windows-phone-7

I've tried to sort my xml file by attribute's value with no luck.

```
data.Descendants("person").OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("id").Value);
```

data contains:

```
<persons>
  <person id="1">
    <name>Abra</name>
    <age>25</age>
  </person>
  <person id="2">
    <name>Cadabra</name>
    <age>29</age>
  </person>
  <person id="4">
    <name>Hokus</name>
    <age>40</age>
  </person>
  <person id="3">
    <name>Pokus</name>
    <age>30</age>
  </person>
</persons>
```

Answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208844/how-to-sort-xml-in-linq-c-by-an-attribute-value-also-mvc) does not work for me.

I'm using MVS 2010 for Windows Phone 7.

I would be grateful for any help.

--

**Update**

Thank You for quick responses!

juharr asked a good question... i was expecting that `OrderBy` would modify `data`. Now i know i was wrong.

I want to modify `data` and i've done as follows (thanks Matt Lacey):

```
var people = data.Elements("person").OrderBy(p => (string)p.Attribute("id"));

    data.Descendants("person").Remove();
    data.Element("persons").Add(people);
```

but i still got nothing. `Data` is empty,  it contains only `<persons />`

I wonder what's wrong now.

---

I manage to solve my problem by using this code:

```
    XDocument datatemp = new XDocument(data);

    var people = datatemp.Descendants("person").OrderBy(x => (int)int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value));

    data.Descendants("person").Remove();
    data.Element("persons").Add(people);
```

Is any other way (more elegant) to modify `data` using `OrderBy` instead of creating `datatemp`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "no luck"?

Comment: Are you capturing the result of the `OrderBy` or are you expecting it to modify `data`?

Comment: I know this is an ancient question. But you avoid the datatemp variable by adding .ToList() or .ToArray() as Dima said. `stuff.OrderBy(...).ToList()` prevents your IEnumerable to be empty when adding to persons.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question you linked to, this works:

```
var people = from p in data.Elements("person")
             orderby (string)p.Attribute("id")
             select p;
```

or

```
var people = data.Elements("person").OrderBy(p => (string)p.Attribute("id"));
```

(tested on a phone to confirm too.)

Comment: this will be sorted by string.sort of int.sort?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you

```
var people = data.Elements("person").OrderBy(p => (string)p.Attribute("id")).ToArray();

data.Descendants("person").Remove();
data.Element("persons").Add(people);
```

Don't forget to use the ToArray() method for your `people`.