# C#: Sort xml node using attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a way we can sort xmlnodes based on attribute values, **consider I can't use linq**. Since I'm using .NET 2.0.

Example:

```
<Root a="1">
   <I aa="1" b="2">
   <I aa="5" b="2">
   <I aa="3" b="2">
   <I aa="4" b="2">
</Root>
```

Should be like ->

```
<Root a="1">
    <I aa="1" b="2">
    <I aa="3" b="2">
    <I aa="4" b="2">
    <I aa="5" b="2">
</Root>
```

Please help.

Comment: I think this is a duplication to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604100/how-to-sort-xml-document-in-linq-by-an-attribute-value?rq=1)

Comment: "He who tries to grab too much will end up with nothing". (it's connected to my deleted post)

Answer (score 12):

To sort use following:

```
var xml= xDoc.Element("Root")
                .Elements("I")
                .OrderByDescending(s => (int) s.Attribute("aa"));
```

Then to save it:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", xml));
doc.Save("C:\\Something.xml");
```

**UPDATE**

You can use XSLT for this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="I">
                            <xsl:sort select="@aa" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And invoke it (quoting [How to apply an XSLT Stylesheet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093/how-to-apply-an-xslt-stylesheet-in-c-sharp) ):

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(myXmlFile) ;
XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform() ;
myXslTrans.Load(myStyleSheet);
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.xml",null) ;
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc,null,myWriter) ;
```

Comment: Garath: I have mentioned in post that I can`t use linq. Please reply with some other answers. Thanks

Comment: Is XSLT allowed? It is in .NET 2.0