# C#: Sort xml nodes and childnodes using attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, linq-to-xml

Referencing the two questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464737/c-sort-xml-node-using-attribute-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604100/how-to-sort-xml-document-in-linq-by-an-attribute-value)
I would like to sort on child nodes as well, but resetting for each "outer" node.
So:

```
<Root>
    <I aa="1">
        <s aa="3"/>
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="5">
        <s aa="3"/>
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="3">
        <s aa="3"/>
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="4">
        <s aa="3"/>
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
    </I>
</Root>
```

Would become:

```
<Root>
    <I aa="1">
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
        <s aa="3"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="3">
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
        <s aa="3"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="4">
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
        <s aa="3"/>
    </I>
    <I aa="5">
        <s aa="1"/>
        <s aa="2"/>
        <s aa="3"/>
    </I>
</Root>
```

I tried different variations of the XDocument sorting, but I cannot get the syntax right.
Hoping someone can help, or provide me with an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some recursion here - each element needs to be cloned and its child elements sorted by the `aa` attribute. A method to do that might look like this:

```cs
private static XElement CopyAndSort(XElement e)
{
    var elements = e.Elements()
        .OrderBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("aa"))
        .Select(CopyAndSort);
    return new XElement(e.Name, e.Attributes(), elements);
}
```

If you then call that with your `Root` element, you will get back a new `Root` element with all its children sorted (and their children sorted, and so on).

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hicsTw) for a working demo.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, that was just what I was needed. I was trying to see some way around foreaching it, but the recursive version is brilliant. Thank so much :-)