# Sorting entries inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I currently have a ListView that contains a listing of names, grabbing from an XML DataSouce. As of right now, everything works as it should, but the names are not in alphabetical order as I'd like them to be. I'd prefer not to use XSLT to recreate the XML file, so is there any other way to go about correctly sorting the ListView in alphabetical order?

Thanks!

Comment: You could order the data when grabbing from the xml data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listview control has a Sort method.

```
public virtual void Sort(
    string sortExpression,
    SortDirection sortDirection
)
```

as from msdn
'Use the Sort method to programmatically sort the data that is displayed in the ListView control by using the specified sort expression and direction. '

details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sort.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208844/how-to-sort-xml-in-linq-c-sharp-by-an-attribute-value-also-mvc) to sort the data?
This will allow you to manipulate the data before passing it to the ListView.

[Another example](http://mstanciu.blogspot.com/2008/08/sorting-elements-in-xml-document.html)

-Jvr

Missed the native sorting, K.I.S.S !